# Where does apple keeps a copy of files when I turned off iCloud drive?

Tags: icloud

I turned off iCloud drive and gave me a popup stating that all documents stored in iCloud would be removed from Mac and presented three options:
Keep a copy, cancel and remove from Mac.

I selected "Keep a copy option" and can't find files in both my mac and icloud.

Where would mac be keeping a copy of my data?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your home folder for a folder called iCloud Drive (Archive).

Apple support document says the following:

> If you turn off iCloud Drive or sign out of iCloud, you have the
>   option to keep a local copy of your files that are in iCloud Drive.
>   Whether you decide to keep a local copy or not, a new Desktop and
>   Documents folder is created in your home folder. [If you choose to keep
>   a local copy, your files in iCloud Drive are copied to a folder called
>   iCloud Drive (Archive) in your home folder.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206985) Then you have the option
>   to move any files that were in your iCloud Desktop and Documents, back
>   to your new local Desktop and Documents.

Comment: When you say home folder, do you mean inside /Users/username?

Comment: If you selected "Keep a copy", the files will be in a folder called iCloud Drive (Archive) in /Users/Username or ~/. If you selected remove from Mac, you may have to go to iCloud.com or re-enable iCloud Drive to pull the files back down.

Answer (score 1):

Open Finder: Menu Bar → Go → Home

Should be a folder in there called "iCloud Drive (Archive)".